# Running time of a function

Tags: performance, time-complexity

I feel the running time of following function

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        sum++;
    }
}
```

is `O(N^2)`
N = number of times the outer loop runs
and

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i*=2){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        sum++;
    }
}
```

is `O(2^N)`
N = number of times the outer loop runs
is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The second one is `O(N log N)`.  Where `N = 1000`........

Answer (score 0):

The first one is O(N^2), because what it does, is adding up all the numbers from 1 to N, and as you know that is solved with the following formula:

```
(N + 1) N / 2 which has O(N^2) time complexity.
```

The second one adds up all the powers of 2 from 1 to 1000 which is solved by this function:

```
2^(n + 1) - 2
```

BUT, in this formula `n` is the maximum power of 2 in the series and 2^n is actually a number dominated by `N`, so we need to put it in terms of N:

```
2^(n+1) - 2 <= N * 2 - 2 which has O(N) time complexity.
```

Comment: for N = 9, 2 ^ (n +1) - 2 = 1022 and 2N -2 is 16. there is a vast difference between the two. I feel 2^(n+1)-2 >= 2N-2. so the time complexity should be O(2^N) or as andrey says it should be O(N log N).

Comment: As an example, try various values of `N`. If `N` is 4, then the time is `1 + 2 + 4 = 7" which is `4*2- 1`, if `N` is 8, then the time is `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15` which is `8*2- 1`, if `N` is 16, then the time is `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31` which is `16*2- 1`

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the first problem by letting `N=10`, the outer loop run `i=1..N`, and the inner loop run `j=1..i`.

Each row represents one iteration of the outer loop, the number of dots signifying how many times the inner loop runs for that iteration.

```
 i | j
 1 | .
 2 | . .
 3 | . . .
 4 | . . . .
 5 | . . . . .
 6 | . . . . . .
 7 | . . . . . . .
 8 | . . . . . . . .
 9 | . . . . . . . . .
10 | . . . . . . . . . .
```

Adding up all the `j`'s gives us the total number of times the inner block gets executed:

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10.

The formula for a consecutive sum from 1..N is:

```
N*(N+1)/2 = 0.5N^2 + 0.5N = O(N^2)
```